# AskTimeoutException: on spray-can server stop

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I am trying to stop spray-can web server with the following code:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
val future = ask(IO(Http)(system), Http.Unbind(10 second))
Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
```

but unfortunatelly I receive the following exception:

> [error]    AskTimeoutException: : Timed out  (AskSupport.scala:334)
>   [error]
>   akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:334)
>   [error] akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$11.run(Scheduler.scala:118) [error]
>   akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(Scheduler.scala:455)
>   [error]
>   akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$12.executeBucket$1(Scheduler.scala:407)
>   [error]
>   akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$12.nextTick(Scheduler.scala:411)
>   [error]
>   akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$12.run(Scheduler.scala:363)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are sending the `Http.Unbind` message to the wrong actor (i.e. the manager actor for the IO extension - in this case, `Http`).

You have to send the `Http.Unbind` message to the `HttpListener` (this is the actor that replies to the `Http.Bind` message with an `Http.Bound` message). The following example sends `Http.Bind` to the manager actor and `Http.Unbind` to the `HttpListener`:

```
class TestActor extends Actor {
  override def preStart = {
    IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(self, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
  }
  def receive = {
    case Http.Bound(_) => 
      println("bound")
      sender ! Http.Unbind(10 seconds)
    case Http.Unbound =>
      println("unbound")
      context.stop(self)
  }
}
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-can/http-server/) section on starting and stopping.